# How do I alter the complete url, not just the path, of nodes?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

When a node's field "External URL" is filled, I want the URL of this node to be that field's value wherever it is rendered/ teasered.

Writing my own service and class using (implementing) `InboundPathProcessorInterface` and `OutboundPathProcessorInterface` I can only alter the *path*, but the base url still gets prepended.

So, whats the correct way?

I thought maybe extending the entity and extending the `toURL()` function might be the trick, but that seems like a lot of work for a simple feature, does it not?

Edit: I know I can just setup redirects, but for the sake of completeness I'd like to know.

Comment: Does setting `$options['base_url']` in you OutboundPathProcessorInterface work?  It's marked as internal, but IIRC that is how the domain-base language negotiation works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InboundPathProcessorInterface can't do it, that's an incoming request, it has no way of redirecting to another site, because that's what you have to do.

Implement something similar to redirect.module: a request subscriber that sets a redirect response.

For outbound processing, that definitely works, but you have to set the right options. Have a look at how `\Drupal\language\Plugin\LanguageNegotiation\LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound()` sets the language domain.

Comment: but how does setting the options help when only the `$path` gets returned?

Comment: The options are passed in by reference.

Comment: I just noticed ♪~ ᕕ(ᐛ)ᕗ